# What AddressSanitizer flags should I use to detect more errors?

Tags: address-sanitizer

What Asan flags should I use to detect more errors? At the moment, I use `ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_stack_use_after_return=1`.

Answer (score 4):

From [Asan FAQ](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer):

```
Q: Can I run AddressSanitizer with more aggressive diagnostics enabled?

A: Yes! In particular you may want to enable

  CFLAGS += -fsanitize-address-use-after-scope
  ASAN_OPTIONS=strict_string_checks=1:detect_stack_use_after_return=1:check_initialization_order=1:strict_init_order=1

Check https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerFlags for more details on this.
```

Answer (score 1):

In command line add these options when compiling :

`-fsanitize-recover=address -fsanitize=address`

When running the executables add these  options :

`ASAN_OPTIONS=halt_on_error=0 ./your_executable_name`

These Options I tried On Ubuntu,In Windows I am still finding answer.